# Generating a View using DbQuery as model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a new Mvc Core application. I want to display a list if items from an sql view. Based on this [article](https://blog.satishyadav.com/How-to-Scaffold-Controllers-with-database-views-to-EF-Core-2-1/), I created a class corresponding to the sql view:

```
public class ItemsUsersAllocations
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then I added the following code to the DbContext:

```
    public virtual DbQuery<ItemsUsersAllocations> ItemsUsersAllocations { get; set; }
```

And the following to OnModelCreating() of the DbContext:

```
    modelBuilder.Query <ItemsUsersAllocations>().ToView("vw_UsersAllocations");
```

I have the following simple action method in the controller before adding any viewmodel:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

And now I tried to auto-generate the Index view. But got an error message:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: What you did differs quite a lot from what happens in the post you refer to.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Yes, it does not use the view, but it was the best I found. I need to use an sql view as a data source to display.

Comment: Then don't scaffold it, write the code manually.

Comment: @Gert Arnold I did, and it seems to be working. Thanks for the idea. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you write (& accept) your own answer, so you can show what you did.

Comment: @Gert Arnold You deserve the credit, plus I am not allowed to show the real code.

Comment: Well, it's not much of an answer. And I don't have any code handy to show an example. Anyone?

Comment: @Gert Arnold I am facing an issue now. When I need to make a change in the database schema, I run Scaffold-DbContext, and as my DbQuery<ItemsUsersAllocations> is added manually, it gets overwritten and disappears. Is there any solution for this? I think that could be made an answer!